# gradle for android mystrios file

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I play with opensource project, and can not find out how
gradle do things, it is like a magic.

I build android package (apk) with gradle.
In "assets" directory in source tree there is no file **X**,
but in apk, if unzip it, there is **X** in "assets" subdirectory.

In `build.gradle` there is no mention about this file,
except one task, but this task not run during build, plus
it should place file in google "oob" file, not into apk.

So, how can I find out how file **X** appear in output apk file?

I tried run gradle with "--info" and "--debug", but no note about this file.

Source code of opensource project is here:
https://github.com/mapsme/omim/tree/master

I run gradle like this `./gradlew clean assembleWeb`

in this directory(https://github.com/mapsme/omim/tree/master/android) you can find build.gradle,
file that interesting to me is World.mwm,
as can you see no such file at:
https://github.com/mapsme/omim/tree/master/android/assets
plus there is no copy or move task in build.gradle for this file or directory that contains this file,
only note about this file in gradle.properties,
but it used only in "oob" tasks, which create "oob" files for google market and that's all.

Comment: *In "assets" directory in source tree there is no file X* ... yes, it is ... fx: `android.sourceSets.amazon.assets.srcDirs = ['flavors/mwm-ttf-assets']`

Comment: Plus, assets can come from [any of the dependencies](https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/android-release-650/android/build.gradle#L32-L62). In a conventional Android Studio project, assets can also come from build-variant-specific directories (e.g., `src/debug/assets/` or `src/amazon/assets/`).